# swf only plays well from within the flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5, loader

please take a look at the following code:

```
    var eee = "";
    var myRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(myURL);
    var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    myRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;
    myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, sendComplete);

    eee +=  "33";
    test.text = eee;
    myLoader.load(myRequest);
    eee +=  "22";
    test.text = eee;

    function sendComplete(e:Event):void
    {
        var varsFromASP = new URLVariables(e.target.data);
        var itemString = varsFromASP.resultStr;
        test.text = eee;
        input.text = itemString;
    }
```

when I run it from within the cs5 flash environment (by clicking ctrl+enter) - it runs as I expect it to run: I see "3322" in the test text box and the string I get from the loader in the input text box.
But, when I run it from outside the flash (double clicking on the swf) it only shows "33" in the test
text box.

anything after the "load" function simply doesn't happen.

any ideas why and how to fix it?

Comment: and what if you remove this line : `myRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;`

Comment: same behavior as before

Comment: did you try to play with the `myURL` ? add `../` etc?

Comment: I'm not using a relative url. myURL looks something like that: "http://www.mywebsite.com/myClassicASP.asp"

Comment: I'm suggesting you download the debugger version of flash. You might get an error you can't see. Maybe you are publishing as "Access Local Files Only" and getting a security violation?

Comment: I changed it to "Access network only". Now I see "3322" in the test text box but I still don't see the string from the loader (which I still see when I run it from flash).

Comment: Also, I've added to the begining of the "sendComplete" function the following lines:   eee += "55";
          test.text = eee;                                but I still only see "3322" in the test text box.

Comment: check crossdomain.xml file

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me your sendComplete function isn't firing.  For some reason its probably erroring out on the load method, so nothing below that fires.  Put a trace inside of sendComplete() and make sure its happening.